# Accessing Azure Assigned Groups via Razor or Controllers in ASP.NET Core

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-active-directory

My ASP.NET Core web app is using an Azure Active Directory tenant and using OpenID Connect to sign-in users. I'm able to login successfully and I'm able to view the full list of Claims on a user with the following code:

```
return new JsonResult(from c in User.Claims select new { c.Type, c.Value });
```

My security token includes the following "groups":

```
{
    type: "groups",
    value: "e8f1a447-336a-47bb-8c26-79f1183f989f"
},
{
    type: "groups",
    value: "38421450-61ba-457b-bec2-e908d42d6b92"
}
```

I'm having trouble trying to determine how to capture these groups to perform logic in my Razor views and controllers. For example, I need to hide/show a button in my Razor view depending on whether a user is in a specific group. In my controllers I may need to allow/deny an action.

What is the standard/preferred method to do this in ASP.NET Core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Azure AD adds applicable group claims to the token it issues for users, the value for the group claim will be the Object ID of the security group and not the name of the security group(a group’s name can be changed in the directory so it is not a reliable identifier for the group ) .You could check whether the user’s existence in the security group in controller by :

```
    // Look for the groups claim for the 'Dev/Test' group.
    const string devTestGroup = "99dbdfac-91f7-4a0f-8eb0-57bf422abf29";
    Claim groupDevTestClaim = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(
        c => c.Type == "groups" &&
            c.Value.Equals(devTestGroup, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));

    // If the app has write permissions and the user is in the Dev/Test group...
    if (null != groupDevTestClaim)
    {
        //
        // Code to add the resource goes here.
        //
        ViewBag.inGroup = true;
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.inGroup = false;
    }
```

Then in view , you could control whether show/hide links/buttons :

```
@if (ViewBag.inGroup)
{
    <div>show/hide button/link goes here</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `AppSettings.json`, add your group's name and GUID object ID:

```
  "AzureAdAuthorizationGroups": {
"MyGroup": "aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee"
```

}

Next, hook up authorisation in your `Startup.cs` `ConfigureServices` method

```
services.AddAuthorization(options => {
            options.AddPolicy("MyGroup", policyBuilder => policyBuilder.RequireClaim("groups", Configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureAdAuthorizationGroups:MyGroup")));
        });
```

Finally in your view:

```
@if ((await AuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, "MyGroup")).Succeeded)
{
    // ...
}
```